# ASP.NET Custom Required Field Validator With CheckBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

[image]

Hello,
I have to implement a form like above. Apart from other required fields, text boxes near the check boxes are not required to be filled in unless the associated check boxes are checked. How can i implement this. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an  onClick client side JS function and then you can enable/disable the validator via JS.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="" runat="server" OnClick="EnableDisable(this,ValidatorID)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function EnableDisable(checkbox,ValidatorID){
  var myVal = document.getElementById(ValidatorID);
  ValidatorEnable(myVal, checkbox.checked); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ... Enabled=<%# checkBox.Checked %> ... />
```

Here, you have to set the `AutoPostBack` property value of the `CheckBox` to *true*.